# what is the name or term for someone with a faulty way of arguing?

Tags: word-choice, names, nicknames, generic-term, argument-structure

What would be the term for some one. for example , who starts an argument by suggesting something absurd, or exaggerated - then as soon as i begin to speak OR begin to point out how obvious the suggestion\claim\grievance is nonsense by ways of simple fact - interrupted because "they dont want to argue" , and i started the argument in the first place, henceforth leaving me the one guilty starting an argument which i have also now lost???

or someone whos method of arguing is not giving the opposing person any chance to say anything, interrupting before 3 or 4 words are said in defense?

Comment: How about 'wrong'?  ;]

Comment: I'm thinking of herd.

Comment: I'm thnking of a$$hole

Comment: I'm thinking of thinking.

Comment: I'd just not bother with them. They don't deserve a name to me!

Comment: Sounds like 'troll' to me.

Comment: They would be called a liberal.

Answer (score 3):

Refusing to have an argument is an example of (somewhat informal) "invincible ignorance" fallacy, whether it's because they are positive they are right or because they just don't feel like talking about it.

The person you describe is *obstinate*.

*Willfully ignorant* is a similar nice term that conjures up a nice image.

Answer (score 1):

*Kangaroo court* refers to a hasty, one-sided proceeding, as well as the corrupt people running it. For an individual, you can use the term *kangaroo judge*.

In the scenario you describe, the person may also be guilty of *gaslighting*: lying to a victim in such a way as to make them doubt their own reason and memory.

Comment: No, gaslighting is a very specific term and concerns psychopathology, abuse/victimization via brainwashing and suchlike. You've watched the movie Gaslight?
Kangaroo court doesn't quite fit either, as it's a sociopolitical term. Here's how it's typically used: _Have you gotten people out this way before? —This would be a first. —Do you know that every day they catch another friend of the shah at the airport? Kangaroo trials and then firing squads... just for having American names in their phone books._

Comment: @TaliaFord: I understand what you mean. These terms *are* used outside of psychological medicine and sociopolitics, though, and they’re as near as I can come to what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of 'you don't know me but I know you' cognitive bias has been (hilariously in my opinion) referred to as ***illusion of asymmetric insight***.

I suspect there must be a label for this under the list of informal fallacies, but in my opinion [*this illusion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusion_of_asymmetric_insight) is quite a fitting term.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say girlfriend/wife or a politician. Maybe a girlfriend/wife who is a politician.

On a serious note, adjectives such as **tomfool, wacky, unreasonable and disputatious** can be used to describe such a person. These would not be sufficient to describe those characteristics individually but would be able to describe the person when they are used in tandem.